# Корректна ли такая запись односвязного списка в файл?

Tags: c, односвязный-список

У нас есть односвязный список, который после каждого изменения списка обновленные данные перезаписываются в файл (вызов функции file_write). При добавлении новых звеньев все работает корректно, но при удалении с помощью функции удаления по значению "deleteNode" или удаления по позиции "deleter" в файл записывается не то что нужно. К примеру, если мы добавим в список такие звенья: "один", "два" и используем функцию "deleter" для первого элемента (в key запишем "0"), то файл будет выглядеть так: "два два ", хотя там должно было записаться только одно звено "два", при этом сам список при печати выглядит корректно как и должен быть.
Пробовал исправить используя другой режим доступа к файлу в функции file_write, вместо "r+" использовать "w", тогда записывает верно, но не уверен является ли такое применения корректным, так как тогда файл открывается и данные перезаписываются (что нужно), но если такого файла нет то он будет создан (что мне не нужно), а нужно только что бы файл был открыт для записи и все имеющиеся в файле данные были уничтожены и записаны новые.

Является ли корректным применение режима доступа "w", в моём случае и насколько правильным является такой метод записи списка в файл, когда я при каждом его изменении вызываю функцию записи которая каждый раз открывает и закрывает файл?

Код (поправлен):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
char name_file[255]; // глобальная
struct Node
{
char data[255];
struct Node *next;
};

void append(struct Node** head_ref, char* new_data) 
{
struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
struct Node *last = *head_ref;
strcpy(new_node->data, new_data);
new_node->next = NULL;
if (*head_ref == NULL)
{
*head_ref = new_node;
return;
}

while (last->next != NULL)
last = last->next;
last->next = new_node;
return;
}

void deleter(Node** head_ref, int position) ///удаление по позиции
{
if (*head_ref == NULL)
    return;
Node* temp = *head_ref;
if (position == 0) {
    *head_ref = temp->next;
    free(temp);
    return;
}
for (int i = 0; temp != NULL && i < position - 1; i++)
    temp = temp->next;
if (temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL)
    return;
Node* next = temp->next->next;
free(temp->next); // Свободная память
temp->next = next;
}

void file_create() ///Создать файл
{
FILE *h;
h=fopen(name_file,"w"); // лля создания нового
if ( h ==NULL ) {
printf("Файл  %s не может быть создан\n", name_file);};
printf("Файл  %s создан и готов к редактированию\n", name_file);
fclose(h);

}

void file_write(struct Node *node) ///Запись в файл
{
FILE *h;
h=fopen(name_file,"w"); // "r+" для записи в созданный;
if ( h ==NULL ) {
printf("Файл  %s не может быть открыт\n", name_file);};
while (node != 0)
    {
        fprintf(h,"%s\n", node->data);
        if (node->next == 0)
        break;
        node = node->next;
    }
printf("Список записан в файл.\n");
fclose(h);
}

void file_load(struct Node** head_ref) ///Загрузка строк из файла в список
{
    FILE *h;
    char mystring[255];
    h=fopen(name_file,"r"); // "r" для чтения
    if ( h ==NULL ) {
    printf("Файл  %s не может быть открыт\n", name_file);};
    while(fgets(mystring,255, h) != NULL)
        append(head_ref, mystring);//загрузка звеньев
    fclose(h);
}

void printList(struct Node *node) ///печать списка
{

printf("--------СПИСОК--------\n\n");
while (node != NULL)
{

printf(" %s\n", node->data);
node = node->next;
}
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUSSIAN");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы в поток вывода
    strcpy(name_file,"Без_имени.txt");
    struct Node* head = NULL;

int keys;//переменная для switch
while (1)// или же while(true)
{
    printf("1. Добавить в конец списка\n");
    printf("2. Печать списка\n");
    printf("3. Создать файл\n");
    printf("4. Load (Очистить список+Загрузить звенья из файла\n");
    printf("0. Выход\n\n");
    printf("Ваш Выбор: ");
    scanf("%d", &keys);
    switch(keys){

    case 0:
    {
        system("CLS");
        break;
    }

    case 1:///Добавить звено в конец списка
    {
        system("CLS");
        printf("Введите Строку: ");
        char numb[255];
        getchar();
        gets(numb);
        append(&head, numb); //добавление_в_конец
        file_write(head);
        system("CLS");
        continue;
    }

    case 2:///Печать списка
    {
        system("CLS");
        printList(head);//печать
        printf("\n\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        continue;
    }

        case 3: /// Создать файл
        {
        system("CLS");
        file_create();//запись в файл
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        continue;
        }

        case 4: /// Load (Очистить список+Загрузить звенья из файла
        {
        system("CLS");
          ///очистка списка
          while (head != 0)
          {
            deleter(&head, 0);
          }
          ///вывод файла
        char name[255];
        ///загрузим из того же файла Без_имени.txt
        file_load(&head); ///При загрузке звеньев в список попадет "/n/n" вместо "/n"
        printf("\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
        continue;
        }

}
return 0;
}
};
```

*При выполнении Load, список:"один(\n), два(\n), три..." превращается в "один(\n), (\n), два(\n), (\n), три...".

*Отдельно код функции file_load():

```
void file_load(struct Node** head_ref) ///Загрузка строк из файла в список
{
    FILE *h;
    char mystring[255];
    char *p;
    h=fopen(name_file,"r"); // "r" для чтения
    if ( h ==NULL ) {
    printf("Файл  %s не может быть открыт\n", name_file);};
    while(fgets(mystring,255, h) != NULL)
        ///Затирать /n
        p = strchr(mystring, '\n');
        if (p) *p = 0;
        append(head_ref, mystring);//загрузка звеньев
    fclose(h);
}
```

Comment: У меня небольшой вопрос: Почему вы не используете класс для своего списка? Код будет более приятным на глаз, и разобраться в нём будет легче

Comment: Ладно, теперь понял. А зачем вы в указали C++ в теге? Ваш код - сплошной C, и если что C++ != C

Comment: @bloody Согласен с вами, по привычке первый добавляю, убрал тег "с++".

Comment: Откровенно говоря, я бы несколько изменил идею использования такой программы. Всю работу с файлом, оставил бы только в п.5 ("создать файл"). И там записывал в файл (открываемый с "w") текущее состояние списка. Ну, м.б. добавил бы пункт -- "прочесть файл", в котором на основе данных в файле с задаваемым именем строил бы новый список (весь старый удалял). Все остальные пункты меняли бы только содержимое списка в памяти. Imho это более логично

Comment: @avp Оставил запись звеньев в файл через "w". Да, согласен, хорошая идея добавить команду очистки старого списка и загрузить новые звенья из нового файла. Реализовал такую команду с помощью функции "file_load" и очистки списка в самом case main (поправил код в вопросе). Но так как я записываю в файл новые звенья построчно (с помощью "/n"), что нужно по заданию, то при выполнении "Load" функция читает записанные ранее переносы строки, и тогда в новый список попадают лишние звенья. Как можно устранить данную ошибку?

Comment: @Vaden, если я ничего не упустил, то вы помещаете данные в файл вызовом `fprintf(h,"%s\n", node->data);`. Я думаю, что читать файл лучше построчно (вызывая fgets(str, sizeof(str), h)`), а `'\n'` в конце строки занулять (что-то вроде `p = strchr(str, '\n'); if (p) *p = 0;`)

Comment: Пустые строки (после зануления (т.е. `if (str[0] == 0)`)) можно отбрасывать

Comment: @avp что вы имеете ввиду под "читать файл лучше построчно", вы про функцию загрузки "file_load" или про запись списка в файл "file_write"? Т.е. где нужно сделать такое применение "читать файл лучше построчно (вызывая fgets(str, sizeof(str), h))" и т.д. ?

Comment: file_load(), конечно. Вы так и читаете, я просто не смотрел на код, когда писал комментарий. Затирайте `\n`  там и проблем быть не должно

Comment: @avp попробовал применить "p = strchr(str, '\n'); if (p) *p = 0;" в функции file_load() в цикле "while(fgets(mystring,255, h) != NULL)" но видимо не правильно (добавил код функции выше в сам вопрос), так как тогда при загрузке попадает только последнее звено. Прочитал документацию по функции "strchr", не совсем понял как в моём случае её использовать. Можете помочь правильно добавить её в мою функцию?

Comment: @Vaden, вы в file_load() скобки после while забыли. Надо -- `void file_load (...) { ... if (h) { while(fgets(mystring,255, h)) {char *p = strchr(mystring, '\n'); if (p) *p = 0; if (mystring[0]) append(head_ref, mystring);} fclose(h);} else printf("Файл  %s не может быть открыт\n", name_file);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@avp, помог решить задачу. Для решения была использована запись с помощью спецификатора доступа "w+", а так же изменена функция file_load() для корректной записи строк из файла в список, без лишних символов переноса строк.
В результате функция file_load приняла такой вид:

```
void file_load(struct Node** head_ref) ///Загрузка строк из файла в список
{
    FILE *h;
    char mystring[255];
    h=fopen(name_file,"r"); // "r" для чтения
    if ( h ==NULL ) {
    printf("Файл  %s не может быть открыт\n", name_file);};
    while(fgets(mystring,255, h) != NULL){
        char *p = strchr(mystring, '\n');
        if (p) *p = 0; if(mystring[0])
        append(head_ref, mystring);//загрузка звеньев
    }
    fclose(h);
}
```